# Can I mix LOOK pedals+cleats with SPD-SL shoes?

Tags: road-bike, clipless, spd, cleat

The pedals and the cleats pictured arrived in one box. Hence they must be "compatible". The shoes arrived in a separate box.

The system used by the pedals/cleats is Look "Keo-style" cleats. The red/orange is reported to have 9° of float.

The shoes are expecting SPD-SL pedals and cleats.

I could attach the cleats to the shoes with no problem. Do you foresee any issues in using this combination?

It's understood walking will be difficult. Let's assume I'll manage to rarely walk while in these shoes.

Online chatter discusses the need for the "SM-SH40 Pontoon Cleat Adaptors". Given that everything works out of the box, I'm assuming that this adapter is meant to facilitate walking, nothing more. Can you confirm?

[image: Mixing LOOK and SPD-SL]

Comment: Don't be tempted to plug the cleat into the pedal until the pedal is on the bike! (don't ask me how I know). Do grease any threads, like the cleat bolts and the pedal thread.

Comment: As a side note, the SM-SH40 Pontoon Cleat Adaptors is for SPD cleats and flat soled shoes (not a common combination) and is not compatible with this style of cleat.

Comment: Very nice! I see the MEC logo, and those look like the Shimano RP1 shoes, I have been eyeing that combo myself, wanting to make the jump up from clips and straps. The thing holding me back is the need to try on the shoes for sizing.

Comment: @Gaston Since I imagine you're also doing home-based fitting, you may want to follow the answers to https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/67137/48599 .

Comment: Thanks Sam, but I'll just wait it out. I have the worst luck when it comes to clothing and shoes.

Comment: Hey Sam, well I ordered my pedals, and got a few other items, but now that the pandemic is basically the new normal, "waiting is out" as I said above isn't really an option anymore. I thought I'd simply go ahead and get the shoes, but now I see MEC doesn't carry the RP1 anymore :-(. In any case, have you had a chance to try them out? How did you make out with measured size vs how they actually fit?

Comment: Don't know my size in Birkenstock, unfortunately. I have some Doc Martens that are US size 10, the label also shows EU size 43. Directly measuring the length of my foot (with socks) I get 27.5 cm which puts it just a tad under 43.5. The half-sizes are typically not available anyway, so that would put me at 44. (this is based on the sizing info for Pearl Izumi Quest shoes). Aaaargh decisions. Is 5 mm about right for size allowance?

Comment: @Gaston Let me just mention one data point. I wear typically size 9.5, with sneakers size 10 or 10.5 (possibly that accounts for sock thickness). The Shimano RP1 at size 43 were too small (too short; not enough length for toes). With size 44 my toes touch the front of the shoes before tightening the straps. Size 44 is a nice fit; snug enough to feel a good grip on the pedals, but still with enough volume inside that I can adjust tightness with the straps.

Comment: @Gaston The front straps appear to be irrelevant. If we tighten the front straps too much, we still won't actually pull with our toes during the up stroke, and the blood supply in the foot won't be affected. The straps nearer the ankles are the only ones that matter. They need to be adjusted just right. Some arteries are apparently squeezed if these are tightened too much, leading to (temporary) numbness during/after a ride.

Comment: @Sam, thanks for this info! I too consider myself 9.5, but depending on sizing end up with 10 or 10.5. Thinking about it, 45 would provide 1 cm of space, probably way too much, the logical start is 44, so I'll do that. About the blood supply, that makes sense. The toes are the "end of the line", whereas the blood supply to the toes must pass through the ankle somewhere. I guess the front straps are more to accommodate the width of the foot. I'm following up with MEC to see if they expect to restock the RP1. If not I'll go with the Pearl Izumi Quests.

Comment: @Sam, how do you find your pedals? I read the comments about how they aren't as "spinny", and am finding this to be the case for me too. The left one will self re-orient itself with the heavy side down, but the right one will stay where. Of course, this is just from messing with them in my hands. I did manage to unscrew the plastic sleeve and pull the whole spindle out of the pedal body, but I think I'll wait to actually ride them a bit to give them a chance to break in before messing with the pedal bearings.

Comment: @Gaston I'm not happy either. In swimming I much prefer a first stroke with my non-dominant (left) side, but at least I can manage with the dominant side. Here I'm in worse shape. Clipless seems to require cycling for 1-2 rotations with one foot only and then fit the other. Here also I'm much more comfortable starting on the left, but it's the left pedal that spins freely and the right seems to have super-viscous grease. I don't yet have a solution, other than to turn the pedal into the right position by foot. They do not seem to be user serviceable.

Comment: I had another look at the pedal spindle. Using a rubber strap tool I took out the plastic sleeve from the pedal body. I thought there was a screw holding the outboard bushing on but neither torx nor hex of any size fits in there, seems to be something that was pressed into place. But even from just messing with it in my hands, I already see the right pedal moving more freely. It is starting to self re-orient itself with the heavy side down. Not as quickly as the other side yet, but it should get better after actual riding with thousands of revs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whilst the shoes are marketed for SPD-SL cleats because that is the Shimano system and you have Shimano shoes, this is really referring to what we call a 'three-bolt' pattern. Both SPD-SL and the look cleats are a 3 bolt pattern so the cleats are compatible with the shoes.

See how there are another two bolt holes in the middle of the three-bolt pattern - in the same manner, those are compatible with any two-bolt cleats, i.e. mountain bike cleats like Shimano SPD, but not limited to one brand of cleat.

You must use the right cleats for the pedals, which is fine because your cleats came with the pedals. Shimano ones look quite alike but aren't the same.

Cleat adapters are indeed for helping you to walk with more grip, as well as to stop the cleats from scuffing and wearing down, but the SM-SH40 are for 2-bolt mtb cleats fitted to a 'road' shoe where they are not recessed. These metal cleats are particularly slippy to walk on if exposed like that.

There is another product, removable covers for plastic 3-bolt cleats, which protect the cleat when you walk around off the bike, but you have everything you need to ride in the photo. Not a whole lot of people even own covers, sometimes I take my shoes off if I want to preserve the cleats and have to walk any distance.

Comment: I have covers for my Keo cleats - in case I need to walk.  They're not small, and they tend to fall off as you walk.  Plus they don't add a lot of stability to the shoe.  A nicer solution is to carry a pair of lightweight shoes, if you can.

Comment: My understanding was you couldn't use Look Keo cleats with Shimano SPD pedals

Comment: @DanK you are correct, this question concerns whether the cleats are compatible with the shoes.

Comment: Shimano calls their road and MTB cleat systems both SPD which might be confusing. The Look and Shimano road system uses the same three hole interface. Look also produces MTB pedals which in turn use the Shimano two hole interface.

Comment: @Carel: No kidding, I hadn't even noticed the subtle SPD vs SPD-SL prior to seeing the answers to Sam's question

Comment: I think that the term "cleat cover" may be more correct than cleat adapter. Cleat covers are rubber covers that go on top of the cleat. They are really, really highly recommended for older Speedplay cleats, until Speedplay started integrating a rubber cover into the cleat. They definitely exist for Look cleats. Shimano SPD-SL cleats have rubber bumpers to facilitate walking already. In any case, cleat covers would protect the cleat from getting ground down when walking, plus they offer more traction on slick floors.

Comment: @WeiwenNg a cleat adapter is a [cleat adapter](https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/si/SI-SH40A-002-ENG.pdf), a cleat cover is a [cleat cover](https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/si/SI-SH45A-002-ENG.pdf)

Comment: @Swifty The last paragraph in your answer suggested that at least one use of an adapter is to facilitate walking. Now the difference between an adapter and a cover is clear.

Comment: @Sam, I had to look twice, my brain was reading it in a particular way. I see it now, edited